# How did Ravana conquer the nine planets?

Tags: ravana, navagraha

As per Ramayana , Ravana conquered the nine planets and influenced the birth of meghnatha ? In the context of this how can any ordinary human being conquer the bad effects of grahas?

Comment: Simply because he was not an ordinary human being. He was a rakshasa who through penance acquired extraordinary powers